# How ValidatesOnExceptions works

Tags: wpf, validation

based on this example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonexceptions.aspx

It seems that ValidatesOnExceptions is responsable to catch the custom exception and add it to Validation.Errors collection.

The problem is **I have the same behavior even with ValidatesOnExceptions set to false**

Could someone explain what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ValidatesOnExceptions` is for custom exception display. But if you have `TextBox` bound to an `int` property then before the binding happen a conversion occurs which could cause "red border".

To try it out

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding IntField}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding StringField, ValidatesOnExceptions=False}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding StringField, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>

public int IntField { get; set; }

private string stringField;
public string StringField
{
    get { return stringField; }
    set
    {
        throw new Exception();  text = stringField; }
    }
}
```

Type a number to each textbox:

1. Red border because of data conversion
2. No red border becauseValidatesOnExceptions false
3. Red border because ValidatesOnExceptions
   true

I hope it helped.

Comment: Yes what you wrote works, I don't understand, but I was doing pretty the same and I was always getting red border, the only different was I use the textbox in a DataGridTemplateColumn. Probably I did something wrong, thanks

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the Version of the Framework you use.

In .NET 4 and 4.5 the answer of nemesv is correct. Still it differs form the MSDN documentation.

In .NET 3.5 when `ValidatesOnExceptions` was introduced, there was no default "red boarder" when the the DataConversion failed. If you want to have that you needed to explicitly add the `ExceptionValidationRule` into the `ValidationRules` of the `Binding`. The [MSDN (3.5-4.5)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonexceptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that you could simply set `ValidatiosOnExceptions` to `true` if you want a shorthand for that.

The problem is that the documentation in the version 4.0 and 4.5 is just wrong as it refers to the  behaviour of the .NET 3.5