# WPF ValidatesOnDataErrors=False not working

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have my own errorprovider and do not want to use any of the built in WPF stuff. I have a textbox that is bound to an integer, and I have ValidatesOnExceptions=False and ValidatesOnDataErrors=False. But when I enter a non integer in the textbox I get a red border. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options

1. You can change your data type to string so that the default converter doesn't throw an exception when converting your data.
2. You can use a custom value converter that doesn't throw an exception when your try to coax a string into an integer

   ```
   class CustomConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return value.ToString();
       }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
           int x = -1;
           Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out x);
           return x;
       }
   }
   ```
3. You can change the UpdateSourceTrigger to explicit and have control over the precisely when databinding is updated.
4. You can use expression blend to edit a local copy of TextBox template and remove all things related to binding validation errors

Comment: @Justin984. You have something similar to what's going on here, it's because you bind to an int: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435030/how-validatesonexceptions-works

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping there was an easy way to shut off the red border without having to edit the template. Thanks for confirming my suspicions. I'll leave this open for a while just in case someone has a clever solution, but I'm guessing this will be the answer.